# Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/' with physical root '' failed to load clr and managed application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My Web API runs OK most of the time in IIS v.10 on Windows Server 2016. However, an error occurs from time to time and I can't figure out the error source or cause. The corresponding Windows Logs/Application error log record is as follows

```
    Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyWebAPI' with physical root '....\MyWebAPI\' failed to load clr and managed application. 
Managed server didn't initialize after 120000 ms.
   Process Id: 4840. 
   File Version: 12.2.19169.6. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: e7f262e33108e92fc8805b925cc04b07d254118b
```

The error results in *HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure* on the client side. After that, MyWebAPI stops working and I have to recycle MyWebAPI application pool manually. 
Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Do you have Hosting Bundle and NET Core runtime installed on the server, by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACM 500.30 means something wrong with the startup.
 
for more info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#50030-in-process-startup-failure 
If you are using 3rd party services like KeyVault etc then surround them with try-catch and log error in the logger.

you can use event viewer for debugging.
 
https://www.happycoder.gr/blog/aspnet-core-20-event-viewer-application-logging/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I published my .net core 3.1 project.

You can get this error if your server is win-x64 and you published to win-x86. If this is the case, you must change the target runtime to win-x64.